# How to make my array patient[6] equals to true and the output should be Approved

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How to make my array patient[6] is equals to true (true, by mean there is data, if there is data inside patient[0] then patient[6] should have the output "APPROVED", and if there is no data in patient[0] then patient[6] should have the output "DISAPPROVED"

This is my codes... How will I make it here...

```
    $sql = "select patientid, firstname, lastname, gender, patienttype, philhealth, status from patients where lastname LIKE '%" . $_POST["key"] . "%' or philhealth LIKE '%" . $_POST["key"] . "%' ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
    $rownum = 0;
    $bgcolor = "";
    while($patient = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $rownum += 1;
        if($rownum == 2)
        {
            $bgcolor = "#FFF";
            $rownum = 0;
        }
        else
        { $bgcolor = "#f9f9f9"; }

        echo "
        <tr id='" . $patient[0] . "' style='background: " . $bgcolor . "' onclick='openphilhealthapproval() '>
                <td id='td27_cell1' style='height: 25px;'>" . $patient[5] . " </td>
                <td id='td27_cell2' style='height: 25px;'>" . $patient[0] . "</td>
                <td id='td27_cell3' style='height: 25px;'>" . $patient[1] . " " . $patient[2] . "</td>
                <td id='td27_cell4' style='height: 25px;'>" . $patient[3] . "</td> 
                <td id='td27_cell5' style='height: 25px;'>" . $patient[4] . "</td>
                <td id='td27_cell6' style='height: 25px;'>" . $patient[6] . "</td>
            </tr>
        ";
    }
```

Comment: some other things you need to watch, you're using mysql which is deprecated, try and use mysqli. Also you're vulnerable to sql injection. you're adding post variabled directly in the query without escaping (or better using a prepared statement)

Comment: Also, you are not using any form of output escaping which can lead to invalid html or XSS vulnerabilities

Comment: I'd recommend just directing him/her to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:
($patient[0]!="")?:$patient[6]="APPROVED":$patient[6]="DISAPPROVED"

Comment: *if there is data inside patient[0] then patient[6] should have the output "APPROVED"*, so I think the ternary should be on `patient[0]`, and save the result to `patient[6]`

Comment: A cleaner version would be `$patient[6] = trim($patient[0]) != "" ? "APPROVED": "DISAPPROVED";`

Comment: @Ash, a value or an expression that resolves to a value is supposed to come after the question mark, not a colon. The entire ternary operation is supposed to be assigned to `$patient[6]`, not assigned inside. This is yours when fixed: `$patient[6] = ($patient[0] != "") ? "APPROVED" : "DISAPPROVED";`

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick:

```
if(empty($patient[0])) {
    $patient[6] = "DISAPPROVED";
else {
    $patient[6] = "APPROVED";
}
```

the empty function gives back false when a value is either not defined or when the value is empty (null,0,false,"",[] and so on). see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: @TobySpeight i've added some explanation. i'll keep it in mind for the future ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator for assign value to patient[6] :

$patient[6]=($patient[0]?'APPROVED':'DISAPPROVED');

Answer (score 0):

For your question, you can assign the value with a ternary operator or if statement. Pick your poison.

Ternary: `$patient[6] = !empty($patient[0]) ? "APPROVED" : "DISAPPROVED";`

If statement:

```
if(!empty($patient[0]))
{
    $patient[6] = "APPROVED";
}
else
{
    $patient[6] = "DISAPPROVED";
}
```

You should not be using any of PHP's mysql functions either, they're deprecated and insecure, use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: I think you mean `mysql` not `mysqli`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT patientid, firstname, lastname, gender, patienttype, philhealth, status FROM patients WHERE lastname LIKE \'%' . $_POST['key'] . '%\' or philhealth LIKE \'%' . $_POST['key'] . '%\'';
$result = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
$rowstyle = false;
while($patient = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($rowstyle)
        $bgcolor = '#fff';
    else
        $bgcolor = '#f9f9f9';

    $rowstyle = !$rowstyle;

    echo
        '<tr id="', htmlspecialchars($patient[0]), '" style="background: ', $bgcolor, ';" onclick="openphilhealthapproval()">', "\n",
        '<td id="td27_cell1" style="height: 25px;">', htmlspecialchars($patient[5]), '</td>', "\n",
        '<td id="td27_cell2" style="height: 25px;">', htmlspecialchars($patient[0]), '</td>', "\n",
        '<td id="td27_cell3" style="height: 25px;">', htmlspecialchars($patient[1]), '</td>', "\n",
        '<td id="td27_cell4" style="height: 25px;">', htmlspecialchars($patient[3]), '</td>', "\n",
        '<td id="td27_cell5" style="height: 25px;">', htmlspecialchars($patient[4]), '</td>', "\n",
        '<td id="td27_cell6" style="height: 25px;">', (!isset($patient[0][0]) ? 'DIS' : ''), 'APPROVED', '</td>', "\n",
        '</tr>', "\n";
}
```

---

PHP uses strings as a byte array, so instead of checking if its "empty" or if the string length is equal to 0, we're just checking if the first byte of the string has been set.

```
$patient[6] = (isset($patient[0][0]) ? 'DIS' : '') . 'APPROVED';
```

or

```
if(isset($patient[0][0]))
    $patient[6] = 'DIS';
else
    $patient[6] = '';
$patient[6] .= 'APPROVED';
```